# Left Shift operation for the value of type Int64 returns negative value after shifting seventh byte in a value

Tags: c#-4.0

Doing left shift operation for the value of type Int64 and after shifting 7th byte getting negative value. These are the values used for 4,5 and 6th bytes 222,157 and 128 remaining bytes are zero. Its working fine in calculator but not in program. Please correct if anything wrong in the code and I am using 64-bit machine.

My code is like this.

```
int value = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
 {
      value <<= 8;
      value |= (byte)messageStream.ReadByte();
 }
```

Comment: "Doing left shift operation for the value of type Int64" - no you're not. Your variable is of type `int`. Ideally, please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, including sample input and expected/actual results.

Comment: oh yeah! sorry for your time Jon, now its working fine i just placed Int64 instead int.